# User Profile is not opening using user LinkedIn Id for different user at the time login in native LinkedIn app in android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am implementing LinkedIn Integration in my android application. I have a requirement to open user profile on android native app using LinkedIn numeric Id of user. I have done this successfully, but the problem is that when I logged out from LinkedIn native app and then open the native app from android application using the user LinkedIn numeric Id, then it redirecting to login screen and after login with suppose user A's credentials and wants to open user B's profile using their Id, then the profile of user A's is opening but I want to open user B's Profile. Please suggest me, How I can implement this ?